# How to install iDRAC onto a r620 server, when I don't want iDRAC

Tags: drac

I just bought a R620 server off of ebay. When I turn it on, the fans go up to 100%. It seems fans speeds are tied to iDRAC, and I'm not able to tolerate 100% fan usage due to noise constraints. However iDRAC doesn't seem to be installed on my system. I read online that installing the iDRAC firmware is free, it's the license that cost money, so I'm looking to try and install iDRAC so I can configure fan speeds.

Currently, when I boot the server, I get this

```
Configuring Memory... Done
Initializing iDRAC... iDRAC not responding. Rebooting
<reboots>
Configuring Memory... Done
Initializing iDrac... <not sure what it says here>
<POSTS>
```

During post, there is an iDRAC initialization error, but it allows me to continue.
Once it posts, I can open up the bios. When I go to the iDRAC settings menu in the bios, it says iDRAC is not installed.

I did try [Platform Specific Bootable ISO](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=490xj), which successfully boots and installs some drivers, but does not mention iDRAC as far as I could tell. This did not change anything related to iDRAC.

In the event of XY problem: I don't care about iDRAC whatsoever, my goal is control over fan speeds.

Here's some pictures of the process:

[image: Initializing iDRAC]
[image: Error in POST]
[image: BIOS?]
[image: iDRAC is not ready]

Comment: On a Dell workstation that I bought off of eBay I had fans running 100 % when the case was open. When pressing and holding the case open alarm switch by hand before poweron, fans went silent. Is it possible that your rack server has a case open alarm switch, too ?

Comment: It sounds to me like the server could be missing the iDRAC card.  See if the server has one, and if it is seated properly.  It usually has an ethernet port on it, with a spanner icon.

Comment: I don't see any case open switches, nor is there any change with the case on @Juergen. I don't think I have an iDRAC card, is there really no way to change *fan speeds* without it?

Comment: I do seem to have an iDRAC port on the motherboard itself, but no removable cards of any sort